# AS3 Hold mouseDown to increase speed/power

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, timer, mousedown

this is what i'm trying to accomplish;

With a click on a movieclip (cannon_mc)
a shot is being fired (ball_mc)

The longer mouse is down, the speed of wich the ball is fired with should increase.
My question to you is;

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?
With a timer or something like this;

```
    var isMouseDown:Boolean = false;
    var speed= 10;    

    myCannon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,buttonPressed);

        function buttonPressed(event:MouseEvent){
            //trace("down");
            isMouseDown == true;

            if(isMouseDown == false)
            {
                speed == +1
            }

        }
```

Comment: did any of the answers solve your problem ? If so please consider marking the most helpful answer as accepted answer. Also don't hesitate to ask for further help if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MOUSE_DOWN event is only fired once. To get the effect you want you need the combo of MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP Event Handlers.

You can set a variable to true in the MOUSE_DOWN event alongwith the current timestamp from `flash.utils.getTimer()`

Then on MOUSE_UP, if the variable you set in MOUSE_DOWN is true, you compute the time elapsed and set the power accordingly.

Example:

```
var isMouseDown:Boolean = false;
var mouseDownBegin:int;
var speed = 10; 
var speed_inc = 2; // give it in per second
var speed_max = 100; // max speed possible

// add event handlers
myCannon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, buttonPressed);
myCannon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, buttonReleased);

function buttonPressed(event:MouseEvent){
    isMouseDown = true;
    mouseDownBegin = flash.utils.getTimer();
}

function buttonReleased(event:MouseEvent){
    if(isMouseDown == true){
        // get time between press and release
        var timeElapsed = flash.utils.getTimer() - mouseDownBegin;

        // reset isMouseDown
        isMouseDown = false;

        // compute speed
        speed += int(Math.floor(speed_inc * (timeElapsed / 1000.0)));
        speed = Math.min(speed, speed_max);

        // code to fire ball with new speed
        // .......
    }
}
```

You can also add an ENTER_FRAME event and animate a power gauge or something for visual effect

**Update**
As pointed to by The_asMan, `MOUSE_UP` event will not fire if the mouse is dragged and released Outside the stage. To handle this case add and event listener for `MOUSE_LEAVE` event with the callback as the copy of buttonReleased function but which takes an Event object:

```
function buttonReleasedOutsideStage(event:Event){
    if(isMouseDown == true){
        // get time between press and release
        var timeElapsed = flash.utils.getTimer() - mouseDownBegin;

        // reset isMouseDown
        isMouseDown = false;

        // compute speed
        speed += int(Math.floor(speed_inc * (timeElapsed / 1000.0)));
        speed = Math.min(speed, speed_max);

        // code to fire ball with new speed
        // .......
    }
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, buttonReleasedOutsideStage);
```

Comment: This is probably close to how I would do it but I would consider mouse up outside of stage.

Comment: You are right the `MOUSE_UP` event will not fire if the mouse is dragged and released Outside the stage. To handle this case add and event listener for `MOUSE_LEAVE` event with the callback as the same buttonReleased function

Comment: Thank you for this great answer and explanation

Comment: Happy to be of help. Also if this answered your question, please mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

(in very short pseudocode)
Write some event handlers:

- onMouseDown: sets flag `_mouseDown`, set `power` to zero
- onFrame: `if (_mouseDown) power++;`
- onMouseUp: clears flag `_mouseDown` and fires ball with accumulated `power`

Framerate independent version:

- onMouseDown: `_loadStart = getTimer(); _mouseDown = true; _power = 0;`
- onFrame: `if (_mouseDown) delta = getTimer() - _loadStart; _power += delta;`
- onMouseUp: shot the ball with `_power`, `_mouseDown = false;`